# Firebase Authenticationでの自動ログインについて

Tags: java, firebase, kotlin

Android アプリでログイン機能を作成しました。
ログインにはuseridとパスワードを使用しています。

その後、2回目以降はログイン画面を介さずに自動ログインをしてメインページへ遷移させたいのですが、方法が見つかりません。

firebase Authenticationを用いて自動ログインを実装しようとしたのですが、Authenticationではemailとpasswordでのログインになってしまいます。
そこで、useridとpasswordで自動ログインを実装するにはどうすれば良いですか？

Answer (score 1):

ログインフォームを表示する前に、onAuthStateChangedを使って既にログイン状態かを調べましょう。